# Is it possible to Integrate a python module in Xcode with my coreML model?

Tags: python, ios, librosa, coremltools

I have trained my `Keras model` and converted it into a `coreML` model.
I have also developed an iPhone app using Swift.

Now I want to extract features from the input audio files using `librosa` library and pass those features to the trained model to get predictions. The prediction results will be displayed on the iPhone.

How can I achieve this? Am I missing out on something? Kindly help on this!
I am new to the Swift and iOS development world.

Comment: Hi, were you guys able to integrate librosa in iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

I have also similar task.
I partially ported libRosa to Swift.
It's in development, but please try:

https://github.com/dhrebeniuk/RosaKit